# Regression Unbiased Estimator

Tags: statistics, regression, parameter-estimation, linear-regression

Suppose $Y_1,Y_2...,Y_n$ are random variables 
$ε_1,ε_2...,ε_n$ are i.i.d with mean 0 and unknown variance
 $\hatβ_0 , $$\hatβ_1 $$,\hatσ^2$ are maximum likelihood estimators

Given $Y_i=β_0+β_1*x_i + ε_i $

How would you proof

$Ε[($$\hatβ$$_0$+$\hatβ$$_1$$)$*$*$*$\hatσ^2$] = $(β_0 + β_1)*σ^2$ (unbiased estimator)

Is the following correct ?

$Ε[($$\hatβ$$_0$+$\hatβ$$_1$$)$*$*$*$\hatσ^2$] = $Ε[E[($$\hatβ$$_0$+$\hatβ$$_1$$)$*$*$*$\hatσ^2$|$\hatσ^2$]] = $E[\hatσ^2$] * $E[\hatβ$$_0
 + \hatβ$$_1 ] $ = $(β_0+β_1) * σ^2 $

Comment: Thank you , I edited the quesiton.

Comment: How do you justify the second equality?